# Powershell calling enable-remotemailbox giving an error

Tags: powershell, hybrid

I am working in a hybrid environment so I need to setup the onprem contact card to sync to Azure AD in the cloud for the exchange online. When I try to do this in powershell, it give me an odd error:

```
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TokenExpiryTime' because it is null."
At C:\Users\ajimmy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_jyaph0hf.fd5\tmp_jyaph0hf.fd5.psm1:7395 char:13
+             $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myI ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletInvocationException
```

Here is how I am calling to connect to on-prem:

```
Function Connect-Exchange {
 
     
    $Credentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your Exchange admin credentials"
 
    $ExOPSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "serverURL/powershell" -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Credentials
 
    Import-PSSession $ExOPSession -AllowClobber

    }

Connect-Exchange
```

When I try to Enable-RemoteMailbox is when it pops the error up top.

```
Enable-RemoteMailbox -identity "$FirstN $LastN" -RemoteRoutingAddress "$UserN@server.mail.onmicrosoft.com"
```

Comment: There are issues with loading both onprem exchange sessions and exchange online sessions in the same context, which makes hybrid a pain. Make sure your exo module is updated. Otherwise, you can try fully disconnecting/reconnecting exchange between commands. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/451786/issue-using-exchangeonlinemanagement-v204-module-t.html